# Maximum modulus principle.

Tags: complex-numbers

Find the maximum value of $|f(z)|$ on the closed complex disk of radius 2,

where $f(z)$$=$$z^4\over{z^2+10}$.

Usually I approach these problems by calculating the modulus squared and simplifying, but here it seems it will slow things down a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: first obtain a good (standard) bound on the largest $|f(z)|$  can be on $|z|=2$. Can you obtain this bound?

Comment: Well, certainly the numerator is less than 16, but I'm am unsure about the denominator. I believe it has a lower bound of $|z|^2$ where $|z|=2$ so at 4. Thus an upper bound would be 4?

Comment: Use the reverse triangle inequality on the denominator.

Comment: So, -8/3 then? The top is 16, the bottom is -6.

Comment: Almost. A negative bound is pretty useless for a positive number :).  But right, you got 6 on the denominator then. (you can use either order for that inequality). So which $z$ gets you 6 on the denominator?  Whoops, I should also say that your negative bound is even wrong (dividing by negative reverses the direction of the inequality, so you would be saying $|f(z)| > $ something negative)

Comment: I'll assume you got that, the point is this is a simple method that avoids computation, because you know that you can do no better than the upper bound, so if you achieve it for some $|z|=2$ you are done. (Ok, minus the more pressing application as to why you can focus on $|z|=2$)

Comment: Well, so it suffices now to find a number which yield this reuslt?

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo yes that's right